# Run python script from Makefile error python3 not a directory

Tags: python-3.x, makefile, shebang

I have a python script (main.py) with the shebang on top like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def main():
  ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

and a Makefile like this:

```
.PHONY: run

run:
 ./main.py
```

I tried to run the script from Makefile `make run` but I got this unfamiliar error:

```
/usr/bin/env: 'python3': Not a directory
make: *** [Makefile:4: run] Error
```

My `main.py` file is an executable file and I successfully run it independently.

My question is how can I make it possible to run from Makefile and what is the problem?

Comment: To clarify, does the command `./main.py` work?

Comment: @NickODell yes, it works

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior (GNU/Linux, make 4.3).  Your example works fine for me.  Please provide details about your setup.

Comment: I am on RHEL 8 (GNU Make 4.2.1). I set the permission to the main.py file like this `chmod +x main.py`. The `main.py` is part of the python package with `__init__.py` there.

Comment: I know the reason. In the Makefile, I have a line of export path: `export PATH := $(shell pwd) /file.toml`. When I remove this line, everything works but with this line, it reproduces the above error.

Comment: Well, sure.  The `PATH` variable contains a list of directories to search for programs to run.  That's what `/usr/bin/env` is looking at, to find the `python3` program.  If you reset it to something else, especially to the name of a file not a list of directories, then no programs can be found.

Comment: @MadScientist I am still not quite sure. The `PATH` is there because I want to run `main.py` with `config` file and it is correct. The error points to the `shebang` locates on top of `main.py` instead.

Comment: `PATH` is a special variable and it definitely should not be pointing to a file. If this is your custom variable, consider changing variable name.

Comment: There are lots of places to go to learn what `PATH` is, but here's one: https://medium.com/@jalendport/what-exactly-is-your-shell-path-2f076f02deb4  You can't change this value without breaking a lot of things.  As @raspy says, you should just choose a different name for your variable.